# Filtering a collection of objects by ID

Tags: c#, collections, filter

Teaching myself some c# and my problem is that I have a class which creates Person objects and adds them to a List (myPersonList). I also have a PartyGroup class which takes a PersonList as one of its properties. My issue is that myPersonList contains the whole results set so at the moment each time it creates a new PartyGroup it adds all the values in myPersonList. Is there a way to tell it to only add those values in myPersonList where the Person.PartyGroupId matches the current PartyGroup groupID we are dealing with. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

//Person

```
using (AseDataReader reader = commandPerson.ExecuteReader())

        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Person person = new Person();
                person.PersonID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["person_id"]);
                person.PartyGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["party_group_id"]);
                person.FullName = reader["full_name"].ToString();

                myPersonList.Add(person);
            }
        }
```

//PartyGroup

```
using (AseDataReader reader = commandPartyGroup.ExecuteReader())

        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int groupId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["party_group_id"]);

                if (myPartyGroupList.Where(partyGroup => partyGroup.PartyGroupID == groupId).Any() == false) 
                {
                    PartyGroup partyGroup = new PartyGroup()
                    {
                        PartyGroupID = groupId,
                        PartyGroupName = reader["party_group_name"].ToString(),
                        PersonList = myPersonList//where PersonList objects contain this groupId???


                    };

                    myPartyGroupList.Add(partyGroup);

                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you just need:

```
PersonList = myPersonList.Where(p => p.PartyGroupID == groupId).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes that line of code makes sense but I am still getting strange results. So I have 3 partyGroups and each should be 10 rows. My select query is sorted by GroupID. What I am seeing is that if I select the first 10 rows my first partyGroup gets populated but not the other 2 which is fine. When I select the first 20 rows it adds 20 rows to the first partyGroup, 20 to the second partygroup and nothing to the third partyGroup instead of adding only the next 10 to the second partyGroup. And same when I add all 30 rows - it adds everything to all partyGroups. Any ideas?

Comment: Mmmh, seeing just the code you posted it should work. Did you try to debug it step by step ?

Comment: I'm doing that now - thinking its something to do with the GROUP BY in my SQL query. Thanks for your help